# What does the word "legal" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning

This is a context from a movie called "The Deer Hunter"

Person 1
What, are you thinking of going deer hunting tonight?
No, not tonight. I'm getting married tonight, and you fu#$%ng guys are
going deer hunting?

Person 2
Hey, first we **get you legal**, tuck you into bed with Angela.

These are some definitions from thefreedictionary but none of them fits here, I think:
a. A person who is legally authorized to live and work in a country.
b. A person or department providing legal assistance.
2. A legal notice, especially an advertisement.

Answer (score 3):

Not everything you hear can be found in dictionaries. Sometimes, you have to rely on the context. Based on the context, person 1 says he's getting married tonight, and objects to his frineds for going deer hunting on such an important occasion. His friend (person 2) tries to jokingly calm him by saying "Don't get upset. First we'll get you legally married to Angela and put you in bed with her, and then we'll go deer hunting."

It's merely a joke between two friends.

Comment: I think it suggests that he has been sleeping with Angela before their marriage, and this will be the first time they can do it 'legally'.

Comment: @Kate Bunting Yes, that is also possible; however, the next part of the sentence says "We'll tuck you into bed with Angela". If they had slept with each other before, his friend wouldn't have felt the need to say that. Also, in the Western culture, I don't think it's illegal for people to be with each other before marriage, so there's no real need to get their relationship legal. But then again, it could mean "We care about you so much that we'd do anything for you, i.e. we'd go the extra mile for you."

Comment: No, of course it isn't illegal for a couple to sleep together before marriage, but _traditionally_ premarital sex was frowned upon, and even at the time the film is set (the 60s, I believe) it was possible to joke about 'doing it legally for the first time'. That's why I used inverted commas.